# Sort two arrays by another in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

I have `two data arrays`, each with the same number of elements. There is also a `sorting` array that has the values in the first array as `unique elements`.

The data arrays can have any number of elements but will each have the exact same number of elements.

I am hoping to have both data arrays sorted by the sort array.

Example:

```
array1(‘group1’,’group1’,’group3’,’group1’,’group2’); (5 elements)

array2(‘data1’,’data3’,’data2’,’data4’,’data5’); (5 elements)

sortArray(‘group2’,’group1’,’group3’);(3 elements, no particular order, one each from array1)
```

The result would be:

```
array(‘group2’,’group1’,’group1’,’group1’,’group3’);

array(‘data5’,’data1’,’data3’,’data4’,’data2’);
```

I tried to get this working with `array_multisort`, but the solution is evading me.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make temporary array corresponding to array1 where for each element of array1 is  set it's index in array2. And sort all arrays  at once

```
$array1 = array('group1','group1','group3','group1','group2'); 
$array2 = array('data1','data3','data2','data4','data5'); 
$sortArray = array('group2','group1','group3');

$flip = array_flip($sortArray);
$sort = [];
foreach($array1 as $x) {
  $sort[] = $flip[$x];      // [1,1,2,1,0]
}
array_multisort($sort, $array1, $array2);

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/939212)

Comment: That is great. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with simple `foreach` loop.

```
    $arr1 = array(1,1,3,1,2);
    $arr2 = array(1,3,2,4,5);
    $sortArr=  array(2,1,3);
    $new_arr1 = array();
    $new_arr2 = array();
    foreach($sortArr as $s){
        foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
            if($s==$value){
                array_push($new_arr1, $value);
                array_push($new_arr2, $arr2[$key]);

            }
        }
    }
```

`$new_arr1` and `$new_arr2` is the resulted array.